# Error seeing results with uLkJSON

Tags: delphi

Hi I am using the APIs shodan to see results in json using uLkJSON, the problem is that when I load the IP program I always returns the error "Invalid typecast" and stops there.

The code is this:

```
unit tool;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ComCtrls, IdBaseComponent,
  IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdHTTP, Vcl.StdCtrls, IdSSLOpenSSL,
  IdIOHandler, IdIOHandlerSocket, IdIOHandlerStack, IdSSL, uLkJSON;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    StatusBar1: TStatusBar;
    PageControl1: TPageControl;
    TabSheet1: TTabSheet;
    TabSheet2: TTabSheet;
    nave: TIdHTTP;
    TabSheet3: TTabSheet;
    TabSheet4: TTabSheet;
    GroupBox1: TGroupBox;
    ip: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    GroupBox2: TGroupBox;
    console1: TMemo;
    ssl: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  api_key: string;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  api_key := 'apikey';
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  code: string;

var
  js,
  itjs: TlkJSONobject;

var ip_found:string;

begin
  code := nave.Get('https://api.shodan.io/shodan/host/' + ip.Text + '?key='
    + api_key);

  js := TlkJSON.ParseText(code) as TlkJsonObject;

  ip_found := js.getString('ip');

  console1.Lines.Add(ip_found);

end;

end.
```

The error is "Invalid class typecast" and appears in this line:

```
  ip_found := js.getString('ip');
```

The error occurs when you use the button, not when I load the program, but the debugger says "exception notification" "project shodan.exe EInvalidCast raised exception class with message" Invalid class typecast "

and mark me this line debugger file called uLkJSON

```
js := FieldByIndex[idx] as TlkJSONstring;
```

JSON Code :

http://pastebin.com/XFNz003X

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you used the debugger?

Comment: Same question in differents locations, same response.
Can you post de content of code variable?

Comment: I rolled back your edit. Please, let's deal with one question at a time. Let's finish this one first.

Answer (score 2):

If

```
ip_found := js.getString('ip');
```

leads to an invalid cast here

```
js := FieldByIndex[idx] as TlkJSONstring;
```

then the obvious conclusion is that the value named `ip` is not a string.

Without being able to see the JSON it's hard to say more than that.

**Update**

You've now shown some JSON. And this is the key part:

```
"ip": 92779150
```

According to the JSON syntax, `92779150` is a number rather than a string which is why `getString` fails. You can use `getDouble` to read the value.

Comment: update with json code, try using getint instead of getString but still gives error.

Comment: The JSON you posted is invalid. Please post actual JSON. In fact. Please supply a complete console program that operates on hard coded JSON. Make it really easy for us to help.

Comment: david, achieved in finding the error field had to use instead of this , the last thing I need is how to detect when a field is null, can do to try but wanted to know how to do it with json , can you help me? Or would you rather make a new post ?

Comment: You need a new post if you want to ask a new question. I think my original answer was accurate. The partial JSON you added to the question confirms that. Can we finish this question first.

Comment: If you post a new question, please post a console app with hard coded JSON. Please cut down the JSON to a minimal form. If we can execute the code directly, it makes the questions so much easier.

Comment: You'd have an answer to the other question, the one you deleted, had you just done it the way I suggested. I'm trying to see the big picture here. I know that if I teach you how to ask a question in as concise a form as possible, that will have a huge impact in your own problem solving skills. Once you learn how to ask well, you'll find that you need to ask far less frequently. Please let me help you.